# Regex broken when encounter linebreak

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match pattern for sql injection prevention.
However, this test case failed.

```java
    @Test
    void testDropPattern() {
        var string = "  {\r\n" + "      \"fullName\": \"Peter Parker\",\r\n"
                + "     \"email\": \"peter.parker@marvel.com\",\r\n" + "        \"birthDate\": \"2000-12-31\",\r\n"
                + "     \"gender\": \"M', '2000-12-31'); DROP table users --\"\r\n" + " }\r\n" + "\r\n";
        var regex = "(?i)(.*)(\\b)+DROP(\\b)+\\s.*(.*)";

        var pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        assertTrue(pattern.matcher(string).matches());
    }
```

It is broken because there is newline character (\r\n) at the end of the string.
This is the original json body with newline.

```json
{
    "fullName": "Peter Parker",
    "email": "peter.parker@marvel.com",
    "birthDate": "2000-12-31",
    "gender": "M', '2000-12-31'); DROP table users --"
}
```

What regex that can be used to handle this use case?

Comment: var pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);

Comment: Not a solution (@ControlAltDel gave you that) but why do you need to test for it? are you sending whatever you get in as raw SQL instead of parameters? Or are you just out to block bots who try to do it?

Comment: Frame Challenge: The fact that you think you need this indicates you are doing it wrong.  If you use a JSON parser, parameterized queries (with "?" for values) and prepared statements, you completely prevent [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) from messing with your database. You can generate SQL dynamically if needed, but never provide data values as literals.

Comment: This is used to create spring filter. I'm working with legacy apps which builds dynamic SQL by joining string, so it's prone to sql injection. Rather than fix all the legacy apps, I try to create web filter that blocks sql scripts upfront

Comment: @Timothy - Just so that you know that >you< will get the blame if your filters are ineffective and your site gets hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Including the multiline flag allows you to run your regular expression without having to work about the new lines

```
@Test
void testDropPattern() {
    var string = "  {\r\n" + "      \"fullName\": \"Peter Parker\",\r\n"
            + "     \"email\": \"peter.parker@marvel.com\",\r\n" + "        \"birthDate\": \"2000-12-31\",\r\n"
            + "     \"gender\": \"M', '2000-12-31'); DROP table users --\"\r\n" + " }\r\n" + "\r\n";
    var regex = "(?i)(.*)(\\b)+DROP(\\b)+\\s.*(.*)";

    var pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    assertTrue(pattern.matcher(string).matches());
}
```

Comment: The regex itself doesn't seem to be correct. Did you try `System.out.println(pattern.matcher(string).matches());`?

Comment: The regex matches his example after 6984 steps. https://regex101.com/r/wl4pjK/1

Comment: This works on the online tester, but not in junit test. Weird

Answer (score 0):

I end up with replacing all newline character before validating regex. Just seems not too clean for me.

```
    @Test
    void testDropPattern() {
        var stringOriginal = "  {\r\n" + "      \"fullName\": \"Peter Parker\",\r\n"
                + "     \"email\": \"peter.parker@marvel.com\",\r\n" + "        \"birthDate\": \"2000-12-31\",\r\n"
                + "     \"gender\": \"M', '2000-12-31'); DROP table users--\"\r\n" + "  }\r\n" + "\r\n";
        var regex = "(?i)(.*)(\\b)+DROP(\\b)+\\s.*(.*)";

        var stringWithoutLineBreak = stringOriginal.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "");

        var pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        assertTrue(pattern.matcher(stringWithoutLineBreak).matches());
    }
```